# CSS3 / jQuery: Accordion hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've this accordion (Closed) as below:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/4.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/4.png)

This is what I see on hover as below:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/3.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/3.png)

**I'm trying to create hover all in green without any light blue are visible as above? How Can I  solve it?**

This is a problem CSS code as below:

```
.trigger a:hover, .trigger a:hover:focus{background-color:#a5cd4e; color:#48c4d2;}
```

This is a whole CSS code as below:

```
.toogle_wrap{background-color:#e4f6f8; border:1px #bfeaf0 solid;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px; width:92%; padding:3% 4%; margin:5px 0 10px 0;} 
.trigger{padding:0px;margin:0; background:url(../images/toggle_small.svg) no-repeat right; background-position:100% -20px; } /* background:url(../images/toggle.png) */
.trigger a{color: #636363;text-decoration: none;display: block; padding:2px 0 2px 0;font-size:16px;font-family:opensans;font-weight:normal; } 
.active {background-position:100% 0px; }
.trigger a:hover, .trigger a:hover:focus{background-color:#a5cd4e; color:#48c4d2;} 
.toggle_container{overflow: hidden;padding:15px 0 0 0;clear: both;}
```

Comment: is this a jQuery Mobile site? if yes you will need to view the source of the generated HTML as jQM adds it's own markup as well, then apply your custom CSS

Comment: where is your HTML code and complete css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change CSS as below:

Your CSS Line:

```
.trigger a:hover, .trigger a:hover:focus{background-color:#a5cd4e; color:#48c4d2;}
```

Need to change/replace CSS Line as below:

```
.trigger:hover { background-color:#a5cd4e; }
.trigger:hover a, .trigger:hover a:focus{ color:#48c4d2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a jQuery Mobile site, use the [jQuery Mobile ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller) to create custom color schemes.